# Не получается реализовать операцию сериализации с использованием async await

Tags: c#, datagridview, async-await

Подскажите, пожалуйста, пожалуйста, пожалуйста.
Я изучил Async и await, и вроде понимаю. Но в моём случае, я вообще не понимаю, как их применить((
У меня имеется функция сериализации.
Но по заданию, операции сохранения и загрузки XML файлов должны быть выполнены с использованием методов async и await.
У меня есть функция, но синхронная. Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать, как здесь реализовать это?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

if (dataGridView1.DataSource!=null)
{
JournalInfo1.Serialize("example.xml", dataGridView1.DataSource as List);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, так:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.DataSource!=null)
    {
        var src = dataGridView1.DataSource as List;
        await Task.Run(() => JournalInfo1.Serialize("example.xml", src));
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56927/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd------).