# Как реализовать десериализацию в этом коде с использованием Async Await?

Tags: c#, async-await

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var GetList = JournalInfo1.Deserialize("filefile.xml");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = GetList;
}
```

вот такая библиотека

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class JournalInfo1
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public string Nam { get; set; }
        public int pin { get; set; }
        public string ras { get; set; }

        public static bool Serialize(string PathToSettingssFile, List<JournalInfo1> ListOfObjects)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(PathToSettingssFile, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<JournalInfo1>));
                serializer.Serialize(writer, ListOfObjects);
                writer.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static List<JournalInfo1> Deserialize(string PathToSettingssFile)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(PathToSettingssFile);
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<JournalInfo1>));
                List<JournalInfo1> GlobalSettingss = (List<JournalInfo1>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                reader.Close();
                return GlobalSettingss;
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                return new List<JournalInfo1>();
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Не дублируйте, пожалуйста, аналогичные вопросы. Судя по всему, вам уже @VladD дал [правильный ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/647563/200400). Для метода десериализации будет точно такое же решение.

Comment: @Nikita это не дублированный вопрос. Там я спрашивал про сериализацию, здесь про десериализацию.

Comment: Ответ одинаков. Асинхронного API для сериализации/десериализации не предусмотрено.

Comment: @andreycha хоть поняли, что за бред сказали?

Comment: Повторю: `XmlSerializer` не предоставляет асинхронного апи. Поэтому единственный способ -- оборачивать вызовы в `Task.Run()`, как и было предложено в предыдущем вопросе.